# Sending Ctrl + Z in a string in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

A quick question... I'm trying to send Ctrl + Z as part of a string that is sent to a proxy (that sends an AT command to send an SMS).

The problem arises because the user can enter  in their command, and then I will take that (as well as the rest of the string to send the SMS) and then change  to mean Ctrl + Z.

I have looked it up already and I am trying to replace in the string  with \u001A... it still doesn't seem to work. Infact, when compiling (this is in VC6) it says:

"warning C4129: 'u' : unrecognized character escape sequence"

...could this have anything to do with why it isn't working? I've tried everything!

Thanks!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would post your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VC6 is ancient, and probably doesn't support unicode escape sequences. Instead of using `\u001a`, try `\x1a`?

Answer (score 0):

To insert a none printable character in a string constant, use  `\<octal-code>`, where octal code is 8-digit-encoded number. Ctrl-Z is 26, that's `\032`, if I am not wrong.

Comment: Something is wrong with the layout of my message, but I think you'll get the answer anyway (by the way Ctrl-Z is numerical value 27)